# Unable to apply SASS style

Tags: html, css, sass

I am pretty new to SASS and was trying to apply a rather simple style to an HTML document using SASS. However, I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>
        <title>SASS Basics</title>
    </head>
    <body>

      <p>SASS Basic</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

The SASS stylesheet that I want to apply is the following:

```
$color = #1a1a1a

p
  display: block
  width: 150px
  height: 100px
  color: $color
```

So the paragraph does not take any of the styles above. Do I also need a CSS file? For now I'm testing it all under: http://sassmeister.com/

Comment: How did you not notice the error displayed in the CSS panel?  `Invalid CSS after "$color ": expected ":", was "= #1a1a1a"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a `=` instead of a `:` :

```
$color: #1a1a1a

p
  display: block
  width: 150px
  height: 100px
  color: $color
```

This is for the syntax. As mentioned by [Marcin Nabialek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24898574/1238019), you'll obviously need to install Ruby and Sass to get this code compiled. [See here for installation procedure](http://sass-lang.com/install).

Comment: Ah, yes. Pardon my blunder. Will accept the answer as soon as I'm capable of.

Comment: Glad to help. I would recommand you to use SCSS syntax, which is more readable and avoid (me) doing several mistakes.

Comment: I would have started right away with it, but I figured I could at least learn basic SASS and then proceed with Sassy. Using Koala as an application for now. Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to convert your SASS file into CSS file. Browsers know only CSS files and not SAS language.

You should definitely look at **Using Sass** section at [Sass page](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html). You can use pure SASS but you can also use Compass framework for instance.

As you see at `sassmeister.com` you have also code converted into CSS syntax, so for simple CSS file you could in theory simple copy this CSS into CSS file but I wouldn't recommend it. You should rather learn how to use SASS watch.

In your HTML document you should then add:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourcssfilename.css" media="all" />
```

to use CSS file.

And also as **[zessx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1238019/zessx)** mentioned you have error in your SASS syntax (I personaly use SCSS syntax)

Comment: Considering the SASS editor on their website does that automatically, why is it that nothing changes?